# Flutter RenderStack object was given an infinite size during layout. How to position container inside stack?

Tags: flutter, render

I am trying to position a container inside a stack but keeps getting this exception.How can i position the container of given size inside the stack using lets say right:0,top:0?The code i am using is shown below:
What changes should i make in my code to make it work?

```
**return SizedBox.fromSize(
            size:Size.fromHeight(300.0),
            child:Container(
                decoration:BoxDecoration(**

                    color:Color(0xFFF3F3F5),
                ),
                child:ListView.builder(
                scrollDirection:Axis.horizontal,
                itemCount:3,
                physics:BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                itemBuilder:(BuildContext context,index){
                    print(10);
                    return Stack(
                        children:<Widget>[
                            Positioned(
                            right:0,
                            top:0,
                            child:Container(
                                margin:EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal:15.0),
                                height:80,
                                width:140,

                                decoration:BoxDecoration(
                                    borderRadius:BorderRadius.circular(16.0),
                                    color:Color(0xFFDDE3F0),
                                ),

                            ),),

                        ],
                    );
                }
            ),
            ),


    );
```

**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this in two way.

1) use shrinkwrap property of listView and set it to true.

```
shrinkWrap: false,
```

2) using column and Expanded. Wrap your ListView with Expanded and Wrap Expanded with Column.

```
Column->Expanded->ListView.
```

Comment: `Expanded` is helpful!

Answer (score 0):

You should give the `Container` that wraps your `ListView` a height.